# Lisp recursive mergesort with ascending order?

Tags: list, syntax, lisp, common-lisp, mergesort

I'm currently trying to write a program that takes two lists of numbers assumed to already be in ascending order and mergesort them recursively.

So far I have:

```
(defun MERGESORT (NLIST1 NLIST2)
(cond ((null NLIST1)NLIST2)
((null NLIST2)NLIST1)
((<= (car NLIST1) (car NLIST2)) (cons(car NLIST1)(car Nlist2))
(MERGESORT(cdr NLIST1)(cdr NLIST2)))
(t(cons(car NLIST2)(car NLIST1))
(MERGESORT (cdr NLIST1)(cdr NLIST2)))))
```

When I write the function to the console with

```
(write (MERGESORT '(1 1 2 4 7) '(1 2 2 3 4 6 9)))
```

All I seem to output is a (6 9)

I want to get (1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 6 7 9).

I might be overthinking the conditions a little and I know it's just a matter of comparing the first two elements, outputting the lesser of the two elements first and then recursing but right now I'm at a roadblock. How would you guys do this program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, this is `merge`, not `mergesort` - the arguments are already sorted.

Your code is really unreadable. With some indentation, it is

```
(defun MERGE (NLIST1 NLIST2)
  (cond 
   ((null NLIST1) NLIST2)
   ((null NLIST2) NLIST1)
   ((<= (car NLIST1) (car NLIST2)) 
    (cons (car NLIST1) (car Nlist2))      ; ?? no effect
    (MERGE (cdr NLIST1) (cdr NLIST2)))   
   (t
    (cons (car NLIST2) (car NLIST1))      ; ?? no effect
    (MERGE (cdr NLIST1) (cdr NLIST2)))))
```

As you can see, your parentheses are just wrong. Always use indentation, to see the structure of your code better.

What it should have been, instead, is

```
(defun MERGE (NLIST1 NLIST2)
  (cond 
   ((null NLIST1) NLIST2)
   ((null NLIST2) NLIST1)
   ((<= (car NLIST1) (car NLIST2)) 
    (cons (car NLIST1) 
          (MERGE .... ....)))
   (t
    (cons (car NLIST2)
          (MERGE .... ....)))))
```